Trying to launch Samsung Wallet using getLaunchIntentForPackage(), but it always returns null
The following code is always returning a null Intent when attempting to launch Samsung Wallet (package name "com.samsung.android.spayfw"):
fun PackageManager.launchIntentForPackage(context: Context, packageName: String) {
    val intent = getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
    context.startActivity(intent)
}

I've verified that package visibility filtering is not the issue, and I am also able to verify from my app that Samsung Wallet is indeed installed on the device by using calling the getPackageInfo() method.
What am I doing wrong here?

You may not be doing anything wrong. That package may not have a launcher activity. If Samsung Wallet has a launcher icon, tap it, then go to Logcat and see what the system logged. Perhaps there is another package involved.
